# Protect image of signature in PDF from being copied

Tags: security, signatures, privacy

When I write letters that need to be sent via snail mail, I print them out and sign them manually.
In the case of letters that can be sent via e-mail, I add an image of my signature using includegraphics.

In such a letter, it’s possible to right-click the image and save it, but I would rather that were not possible.
Can it be made impossible or at least difficult?

Comment: You can right click and extract an image from a PDF? I'm surprised, which pdf viewer are you using?

Comment: Usually mupdf, but I tried it in evince. It works.

Comment: wow, it is true that now is possible, ... but try with a  pdf image (a draw from inkscape with some layers saved as pdf) and you will see ...

Comment: @Fran Can you explain what I should do with the existing png image I have? I open it in inkscape, and then? Simply save as pdf? When I use the newly created pdf as image instead of the png, it is as extractable as the png

Comment: Maybe you can prevent this specific way of storing the image (although I doubt it), but you cannot prevent screenshots.

Comment: @Marijn I know, but it would be nice to at least be able to prevent my own signature file from being directly reused (without even having to put in any effort whatsoever) by someone else.

Comment: @Philipp I understand your sentiment, but I think that if somebody is willing to commit identity fraud then they are also willing to make a screenshot.

Comment: @Philipp A bitmap image as a PNG file inserted in a PDF image  is still as PNG image that can be extracted, but a PNG signature vectorized and  saved as PDF is not. If you add a PNG background ***under*** that signature, you can save it again ... but the background part only. However, that are nothing against screenshots ... except that it will no longer a vectorized image and it will lost quality.  But you can edit the PDF with Inkscape and the extract the signature as  vectorial draw, so ...

Comment: @Fran Using a vector image converted to pdf works fine! Please make that into answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add scanned PNG image of the signature to Inkscape, vectorize it, then remove PNG image, save the draw as PDF and use it as image in the LaTeX file. Then the menus to save the image disappear. Using the signature as a layer on top of a PNG image, the option to save the image will  available again, but only to save the PNG background, simulating some anti-copy mechanism. A trasparent PNG of top of the vectorized also will work in thi sense.

Moreover, making some small modification of the signature (for instance, a very very tiny text inside some trace, invisible without a huge zoom) the screenshot will not reproduce exactly the signature, so it can be checked easily that is not the original, as it will be pixelated after some zoom. However, it can be extracted unaltered with Inkscape, so there are not secure methods, except use also a [digital signature](https://acrobat.adobe.com/il/en/sign/capabilities/digital-signatures-faq.html).